# Warning paper stapled to back cover of passport

Tags: visas, passports

I recently applied for a schengen visa, and when i got my passport back , i found a paper stapled at the back as a warning that the visa is only for vacation purposes and not work or other things.
Now i already know that the embassy has the right to staple on pages of the passport , but i don't understand why they did so on the back cover of the passport. Is it even legal to do so ?

Comment: Many embassies do the same thing. Same thing with some airlines which affix stickers to passports.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen yes some old passports had stickers on the back but never a paper stapled

Comment: I have several papers stapled to my previous passport just a couple years ago by the French and Brazilian embassies etc. And the USA used to staple an envelope containing documents for students and immigrant visa holders

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen Thank you for your reply and clarification. I find it really irresponsible of them to staple a paper to the back of a passport, instead of using the papers inside. At least that's what they are for...

Comment: What is your concern? The potential to damage the passport?

Comment: Was the ***visa*** stapled on or stamped inside the passport? If the stapled note is just a reminder to you, why not remove it?

Comment: *Is it even legal to do so?* This is too broad. Legal for who? Legal for whoever did the stapling in their own country? Legal with respect to your country's laws? And if it is technically illegal according to your country's law, what difference does it make?

Comment: Note that some of these workers at the embassy do these things not due to standard operating policy but rather haphazard convenience. It is generally accepted everywhere things should not be stapled to passports but they don't care.

Comment: @WeatherVane No this is just a note,  stating that this not a work visa. The problem with removing it, is that it will leave two big holes behind, which might look suspicious.

Comment: Why? No-one will staple any official restriction or ban to the passport, they will stamp a page with an endorsement. Presumably the visa already states its type.

Comment: @MJeffryes legal in the sense that the passport is the country's property. If i, as the holder of this passport, could be pursued for damaging it in anyway, why should a foreign embassy worker puncture two holes in the back ? And not use the papers inside for their intended usage ?

Comment: My two cents is it is not worth getting upset over. These embassy types know they can get away with anything.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen yes exactly, as you stated before one would think that they would follow common practice. Thank you again for replying.

Comment: I think if you reframed the question as something like "will I face any issues traveling on a passport with holes in", it would be acceptable. But as it is, this feels like more of a complaint than a question.

Comment: @WeatherVane a standard way to indicate a passport is cancelled is to put holes in the cover and the identification page.  Granted, these holes will be smaller by a few orders of magnitude, but they could nonetheless cause problems with countries or individual border officers who are particularly strict about the condition of the passport.

Comment: @phoog I understand the concern. In India a damaged or imperfect banknote may not be accepted, so what of a passport? In UK a passport is invalidated by cutting off its corners.

Comment: @phoog My passport is full of staple holes. As long as the biographic page of the newest one isn't damaged, it's not going to be a problem. I've been to consulates who themselves attach passports with staples and others who remove them.

Comment: @greatone are any of those staple holes in the cover?  Have you used that passport to travel to India?

Comment: @phoog Yes. The back cover. Many times. I even have a passport page where a sticker was removed leaving residue (I suspect this was by visa officials someplace). The India officials have even used that page to make annotations.

Comment: @phoog The holes in the cover are very different from staple holes. The holes remove part of the MRZ, the information lines read by OCR, so they won't be accepted by automated systems. Before the MRZ, the US just put a big stamp over the biographic data.

Comment: @user71659 that is correct, but it is no guarantee that an immigration officer will accept a passport with staple holes in its cover.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the legality of it, but if your passport is one of those that works with the automatic gates, then stapling through one of the stiffer parts of your passport runs the risk of damaging the RFID antenna inside.  You might want to check with your passport issuing authority.